# AngularJS conditional case for .then based on var value known only before the first .then

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, conditional-statements, angular-promise

I have a code that works fine:

```
    myService.myFunc1()
        .then(myService.myFunc1)
        .then(function(dataA) {
            // do something
        })
        .then(myService.myFunc2)
        .then(function(dataB) {
            //do something
        });
```

However, upon `myFunc1` execution, the value for boolean `myService.trig` is set properly.  I'd like to change the code above to make it conditional based on the `myService.trig` boolean value and decide whether to execute all the rest .then (for true) after  `myService.myFunc1().` or execute one another .then INSTEAD (for false).

How can it be done in angularJS way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to check in every callback what the value of ``myService.trig` is.

```
myService.myFunc1()
     .then(() => {
         // execute this function if the "myService.trig" is true
         if (!myService.trig) return;
         return myService.myFunc1;
     })
     .then((dataA) => {
         // execute this function if the "myService.trig" is true
         if (!myService.trig) return;
         // do something
     })
     .then(() => {
         // execute this function if the "myService.trig" is false
         if (myService.trig) return;
         return myService.myFunc2;
     })
     .then((dataB) =>  {
         // execute this function if the "myService.trig" is false
         if (myService.trig) return;
         // do something
     });
```

Or you could nest the promises so you don't have to check for the value all the time. But to he honest, I would prefer the repeated checking than nesting promises.